# Bars not properly displaying in TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I have run into this Issue where I try to have 2 Barcharts next to each other, but for some reason the second one is really weirdly positioned and stretched. I have similar charts with the same code, where it works. The only difference is that in the second [axis] there are only 2 groups of bars instead of 4. When I try to have the x=11m or sth in it, its completely clipped. Thanks for the Help

```
\begin{figure}[]
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]

 \begin{axis}[align= center, title  =  Warst du schon einmal von Grenzüberschreitung\\ betroffen oder hast diese wahrgenommen? \footnote{GÜFrage},
    legend style={
        legend columns=1,
        draw=none,
    },
    x= 11mm,
    ybar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    ylabel= Antworten in Prozent,
    ymax = 100,
    ymin = 0,
    symbolic x coords = {Betroffen, Beobachtet, Beides, Weder noch},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style = {rotate=45, anchor=east, font=\footnotesize},
  ]
  \addplot [fill = colorBarWomen, draw = colorBarWomen] coordinates  { (Betroffen, 8.4) (Beobachtet, 16.8) (Beides, 9.9)  (Weder noch, 64.9) };
  \addplot [fill = colorBarMen, draw = colorBarMen] coordinates { (Betroffen, 9.7)         (Beobachtet, 23.6) (Beides, 5.6)   (Weder noch, 61.1)  };
\legend {Frauen, Männer};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
 
  \begin{axis}[align=center, title  =  Welches Geschlecht würdest du der\\ Grenzüberschreitenden Person zuordnen?\footnote{GÜFrage 2},
      legend style={
        legend columns=1,
        draw=none,
    },
    ybar,
    axis y line=right,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    x axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    ymax = 100,
    ymin = 0,
    symbolic x coords = {Bei Betroffenheit, Bei Beobachtung},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style = {rotate=45, anchor=east, font=\footnotesize},
  ]
  \addplot [fill = colorBarWomen, draw = colorBarWomen] coordinates  { (Bei Betroffenheit, 18.4) (Bei Beobachtung, 12.3) };
  \addplot [fill = colorBarMen, draw = colorBarMen] coordinates { (Bei Betroffenheit, 81.6) (Bei Beobachtung, 93.0) };  
  \addplot [fill = colorBarDivers, draw = colorBarDivers] coordinates { (Bei Betroffenheit, 0.7) (Bei Beobachtung, 3.5) };
  \legend {Weiblich gelesen, Männlich gelesen, Divers gelesen};
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

[image: here is what it looks like]

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

%Ich untersuche die Umsetzung des Sexualkundeunterrichts an weiterführenden Schulen in Bayern, weil ich herausfinden möchte, wie dessen Zustand momentan an den Schulen ist und um Weiterentwicklungsmöglichkeiten herauszuarbeiten.
\title{Praxisbericht zur münchener Aidshilfe}
\author{Rafael Pietsch (Matrikelnr. 31527)}
\date{Februar 2023}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\usepackage[style=fiwi2,publisher=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}     % for colour
\usepackage{ntheorem}   % for theorem-like environments
\usepackage{mdframed}   % for framing
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{subcaption}

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\newmdtheoremenv[%
linecolor=gray,leftmargin=30,%
rightmargin=30,
backgroundcolor=gray!40,%
innertopmargin=5pt,%
ntheorem]{myprop}{Situation}



\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newread\tmp

\newcommand*{\SignatureAndDate}[1]{%
    \par\noindent\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}%
    \par\noindent\makebox[2.5in][l]{Ort, Datum}      \hfill\makebox[2.5in][l]{#1}%
}%

\let\oldquote'
\newif\ifquoteopen
\catcode`\'=\active
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{'}{%
   \@ifnextchar'{%
     \ifquoteopen
       \global\quoteopenfalse\grqq\expandafter\@gobble
     \else
       \global\quoteopentrue\glqq\expandafter\@gobble
     \fi
   }{\oldquote}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
%\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}


\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum -merge -q #1.tex output.bbl > #1-words.sum }%
  \input{#1-words.sum} words%
}

\newcommand{\quickcharcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -1 -sum -merge -char -q #1.tex output.bbl > #1-chars.sum }%
  \input{#1-chars.sum} characters (not including spaces)%
}


\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{20pt}


\begin{document}


%\quickwordcount{main}
%\quickcharcount{main}

%There are \thechar characters and approximately \theword spaces.
%hat makes approximately \the\numexpr\theword+\thechar\relax\ characters total.


%\includepdf{Deckblatt.pdf}

\maketitle

\newpage

\tableofcontents{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\newpage



\subsection{Analyse der Demografik}

\input{Auswertung 1}

\subsection{Auswertung der Relevanz des Kellers im Campusleben der KSH}

\input{Auswertung 2}


\subsection{Finanzierung der Einrichtung}

\input{Auswertung 3}

\section{Methodische Möglichkeiten der Arbeit}



\section{Berufliche Aufgaben und Stellung von Sozialpädagog*innen in der Institution}


\nocite{*}
\newpage
\printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis},heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small compilable document beginning with \documentclass{...} and ending with `\end{document}`. Your definitions of colors, page layout are unknown ...

Comment: You could try with `enlarge x limits=1` as option to the `axis`.

Comment: I added the main part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            hmargin=3cm, vmargin={2.5cm, 2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\pgfplotsset{width=0.45\linewidth,
    legend style={draw=none, 
                  cells={anchor=west},
                  font=\footnotesize},
    ybar,
    y axis line style = {draw=none},
    xtick = none,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 100,
    xtick=data,
        tick style={draw=none},
x tick label style = {rotate=45, anchor=east, font=\footnotesize},
            }
            
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
 \begin{axis}[width=0.45\linewidth,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    title=\parbox{0.45\linewidth}{\small\centering
            Warst du schon einmal von Grenzüberschreitung
            betroffen oder hast diese wahrgenommen? \footnote{GÜFrage}},
    symbolic x coords = {Betroffen, Beobachtet, Beides, Weder noch},
          ]
  \addplot [fill = red, draw = red] coordinates  { (Betroffen, 8.4) (Beobachtet, 16.8) (Beides, 9.9)  (Weder noch, 64.9) };
  \addplot [fill = blue, draw = blue] coordinates { (Betroffen, 9.7)         (Beobachtet, 23.6) (Beides, 5.6)   (Weder noch, 61.1)  };
\legend {Frauen, Männer};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\hfil
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[width=0.45\linewidth,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    title=\parbox{0.45\linewidth}{\small\centering
            Welches Geschlecht würdest du der
            Grenzüberschreitenden Person zuordnen?\footnote{GÜFrage 2}},
    symbolic x coords = {Bei Betroffenheit, Bei Beobachtung},
                ]
  \addplot [fill = blue, draw = blue] coordinates  { (Bei Betroffenheit, 18.4) (Bei Beobachtung, 12.3) };
  \addplot [fill = red, draw = red] coordinates { (Bei Betroffenheit, 81.6) (Bei Beobachtung, 93.0) };
  \addplot [fill = teal, draw = teal] coordinates { (Bei Betroffenheit, 0.7) (Bei Beobachtung, 3.5) };
  \legend {Weiblich gelesen, Männlich gelesen, Divers gelesen};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(gray lines indicate text block borders)

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks for bearing through my awfully spaced code.